# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() not working with AdobeImageIntent.EXTRA_OUTPUT_URI

Tags: android, bitmap, android-7.0-nougat, adobecreativesdk

I recently updated adobecreativesdk with the latest version to support Android Nougat. After i edit the image in the editor i try to get the edited bitmap using the following code in onActivityResult:

```
  mImageUri = data.getParcelableExtra(AdobeImageIntent.EXTRA_OUTPUT_URI);

                    Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageUri.getPath());

                    if(bitmap!=null)
                    {

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                   imagebytes = baos.toByteArray();

                    PlayAnimation();
                    }
```

Before updating to the latest version I was using data.getData() instead of data.getParcelableExtra and it was working fine for Android Marshmallow. But now my bitmap is always returned as null. I have set the URI of the image just like how it has been mentioned in this post :
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en. I also tried resizing the bitmap using BitmapFactory.Options thinking maybe the image was too big. But it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: `mImageUri.getPath()`. Please tell the path. It might be part of a content sheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Uri` to image it is better to read it via `ContentResolver`:

```
Uri uri;
Context context;
try {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`ContentResolver` handles underlying storage differences for you. It works equally fine with both `file://`, `content://` and other `Uri` types.